# Memory leak with type vector<A>* in cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-management, heap-memory

Is there any memory leak in the below code section. I have a class A and a method that returns a pointer to vector of type A.

```
class A{
  public:
        shared_ptr<int> a;
};

vector<A>* _array(){
    // some code 
    return new vector<A>();
}

int main(){
    vector<A> *a = _array();
}
```

Comment: One should almost *never* have pointers to containers. Having such a pointer should be considered a red flag, that you're probably doing something you should not be doing.

Comment: `vector<A> _array(){ return {}; }` -- That same code is probably more efficient and safe than what you posted.

Comment: Why do you think there *wouldn't* be a memory leak? It's no different from `int* f() { return new int; } int main() { int* p = f(); }`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in `main()` you assign what `_array()` allocates to `*a` but never free it. To fix it, you need to `delete a;`.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the pointer.

```
class A{
  public:
        shared_ptr<int> a;
};

vector<A> _array(){
    // some code 
    return vector<A>();
}

int main(){
    vector<A> a = _array();
}
```

Not sure why you are using a pointer there, so I can't make any specific criticism, but probably the pointer is unnecessary. Most reasons given by newbies for using pointers are invalid.

Just realised I didn't answer the question. Yes there is a memory leak in your code. Arguably a harmless one, because the memory will be recovered when your program exits, but a leak nevertheless.